# Loops for cat links not looping for wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I have this code and all the vars pull in but the latest news is not showing up. any ideas?

```
<div class="content">
    <?php get_sidebar('field'); ?>
    <?php
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    $user_info = get_userdata($current_user->ID);

    if ( have_posts() && $user_info->user_level != 0) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php // get custom fields
    $wt_email = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wt_email', true);
    $wt_feed = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wt_website', true);
    $wt_facebook = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wt_facebook', true);
    $wt_twitter = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wt_twitter', true);
    $wt_linkedin = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wt_linkedin', true);
    ?>

    <div class="entry">
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <div class="body">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="share">
        <div class="links">
            <h3>Links</h3>
            <ul>
                <?php if($wt_twitter) { ?><li><a href="http://<?php print $wt_twitter; ?>">Twitter</a></li><?php } ?>
                <?php if($wt_facebook) { ?><li><a href="http://<?php print $wt_facebook; ?>">Facebook</a></li><?php } ?>
                <?php if($wt_email) { ?><li><a href="mailto:<?php print $wt_email; ?>">Email</a></li><?php } ?>
                <?php if($wt_linkedin) { ?><li><a href="http://<?php print $wt_linkedin; ?>">Website</a></li><?php } ?>
            </ul>
            </div>
<?php endwhile; // End the loop. Whew. ?>
        <div class="news">
            <h3>Latest News</h3>
            <ul>
                <?php
                // The Query
                $loop = new WP_Query( array( 
                    'category_name' => $wt_feed, 
                    'order' => 'ASC', 
                    'posts_per_page'=> 5
                ) );

                // The Loop
                if( $loop->have_posts() ) : while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                    echo '<li><a href="' . the_permalink() . '">';
                        the_title(); 
                    echo '</a></li>';
                endwhile;
                endif;

                // Reset Query
                wp_reset_query();
                ?>
            </ul>
            <?php 
            $args=array(
              'category_name'       => $wt_feed,
              'type'                => 'post'
              );
            $categories=get_categories($args);

            if($wt_feed) { ?><a href="/<?php print $categories->slug; ?>/feed" class="subscribe">Subscribe</a><?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <?php else : ?>
    <div class="entry">
    <h1>Listing Private</h1>
    <div class="body">
    <p>You need to have a Member account view the details of this list. Request an account membership.</p>
    </div>
    </div>

    <?php endif; ?>

<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whilst not an exact answer, have you tried adding:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

At the top of the page, to display any errors that might be occurring?